# Convert object to CSV string

Tags: c#, string, csv, object

I am having problems converting an object of products into a csv string.

```
var data = ProductPresenter.ExportAllProducts();
string csv = String.Join(",", data.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
```

**This produces an output of:**

```
BLL.Views.ExportAllProducts,BLL.Views.ExportAllProducts,BLL.Views.ExportAllProducts,BLL.Views.ExportAllProducts,BLL.Views.ExportAllProducts,BLL.Views.ExportAllProducts,BLL.Views.ExportAllProducts,BLL.Views.ExportAllProducts,BLL.Views.ExportAllProducts,BLL.Views.ExportAllProducts,BLL.Views.ExportAllProducts,BLL.Views.ExportAllProducts,BLL.Views.ExportAllProducts,BLL.Views.ExportAllProducts,BLL.Views.ExportAllProducts,BLL.Views.ExportAllProducts,BLL.Views.ExportAllProducts,BLL.Views.ExportAllProducts
```

**Expected output would be like:**

```
Small Hat, 12.10, true
Medium Hat, 13.50, true
Large Hat, 15.00, false
...
```

What conversion am I missing to get the values out of each item on the object?

Comment: What does the **ExportAllProducts** method do? Could you show us some code?

Comment: By default, `.ToString()` on a reference type just prints the name of the type.  What is the type of `data`?  Have you overridden the default behavior of `.ToString()` on it?

Comment: I would assume ExportAllProducts returns an array of objects and therefore the string.join returns an "{object}","{object}" sort of array and not the result join of all properties of the object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to convert a list of objects to csv with each object values in a new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25683161/fastest-way-to-convert-a-list-of-objects-to-csv-with-each-object-values-in-a-new)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data variable is not a list of strings, either add a .ToString() method to that class or create a list of strings and use that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `ToString()` method in order to have the desired effect. Otherwise, the implementation of `ToString()` from the base "Object" class is used when you do `x.ToString()`.

`Object.ToString()` returns the full name of the class of which your object is an instance of.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to get a list/array of strings in csv format.

I'd override [`ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173154%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
class Product
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ProductName + "," + Price.ToString() + "," + boolProperty.ToString();
    }
}
```

and

```
var q = (from d in data select d.ToString()).ToArray()
```

or something like

```
var q = (from d in data 
        select new { d.ProductName + "," + Price.ToString() +
               "," + boolProperty.ToString() } )
        .ToArray()
```