# Create comma separated list from list of objects

Tags: c#, list, csv

I have list of objects type Person. This class has many properties and I need them all in a comma separated list so I can use it later for Csv file.

I've managed this with foreach and adding each property, separating it with commas manual, etc.

```
const string commaSeparator = ",";
foreach (var item in individualsInformation)
{
    csv.AppendLine(item.ReferenceNumber + commaSeparator + item.FirstName + commaSeparator +
                   item.Surname + commaSeparator + item.MiddleName + commaSeparator +
                   item.Address1 + commaSeparator + item.Address2 + commaSeparator + 
                   item.Address3 + commaSeparator + item.Address4 + commaSeparator + 
                   item.City + commaSeparator + item.PostalCode + commaSeparator +
                   item.Country + commaSeparator + item.DateOfBirth.ToString() + commaSeparator +
                   item.ID + commaSeparator + item.Gender + commaSeparator +
                   item.Component + commaSeparator + item.NationalID + commaSeparator + 
                   item.SubSystemID + commaSeparator + item.System);
}
```

Then I've realized that there is much efficient way, by using string.Join

This does not work of course:

```
string joined = string.Join(",", listOfPersons);
```

And if I go by selecting property like this:

```
string joined = string.Join(",", listOfPersons(x => x.Id);
```

I get comma separated list only for that property of course.

Is there some more efficient way for getting each property separated by comma?

Comment: Stop trying to reinvent the wheel. Check the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25684175/1641172)

Comment: Your current approach isn't all bad and the only way to have full control on everything.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would avoid reflection if possible.

You can achieve it with compile time safety and readable code easily:

```
IEnumerable<string> personTexts = listOfPersons
    .Select(p => String.Join(",", p.ReferenceNumber, p.FirstName, p.Surname, ...));
string joined = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, personTexts);
```

You have full control over which property should be used and in which order.

Answer (score 7):

Reflection is (sometimes) your friend:

```
var props = item.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance); // todo: cache & filter not-needed props)

var itemStr = string.Join(", ", 
                     props.Select(p => p.GetValue(item, null)?.ToString())
                          .ToArray());
```

Comment: Reflection totally helped. Thanks! :) @nopeflow

Answer (score 4):

Overrride the `ToString`-Method for your Person-Class

```
public class Person
{
    //properties...

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(",",
            this.ReferenceNumber,
            this.FirstName,
            this.Surname,
            this.MiddleName,
            this.Address1,
            this.Address2,
            this.Address3,
            this.Address4,
            this.City,
            this.PostalCode,
            this.Country,
            this.DateOfBirth.ToString(),
            this.ID,
            this.Gender,
            this.Component,
            this.NationalID,
            this.SubSystemID,
            this.System);
    }
}
```

so you can use `Person.ToString()` for csv-generation. Unlike the reflection approach you can easy

- maintain the order
- handle each type different (`BirthDate.ToString("d")`, `Price.ToString("F2")`)
- skip values you don't need e.g. `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]`
- change values to your requirements (`HasChildren ? "Yes" : "No"`)

Answer (score 0):

Using Reflection where T : class

> var valueLines =reportData.Select(row => string.Join(",", header.Split(',').Select(a => row.GetType().GetProperty(a).GetValue(row, null))));

eg

```
private MemoryStream GenerateExcelStream(List<T> reportData)
    {
        var lines = new List<string>();
        var header = "";
        var attFilter = new NoDisplayInReportAttribute();
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            if (!prop.Attributes.Matches(attFilter))
                header += prop.Name + ",";
        header = header.Substring(0, header.Length - 1);
        lines.Add(header);
        var valueLines =reportData.Select(row => string.Join(",", header.Split(',').Select(a => row.GetType().GetProperty(a).GetValue(row, null))));
        lines.AddRange(valueLines);
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
        lines.ForEach(x => tw.WriteLine(x));
        tw.Flush();
        return memoryStream;
    }
```